# How to use EpicenterCallback?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I am using an Explode transition between two activities. I want to set the explode effect such that other views move away from the view that is touched. [EpicenterCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.EpicenterCallback.html) seems like it would fit this purpose, but I cannot get my transition to actually trigger onGetEpicenter. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the method I have to set the callback and start the transition:

```
public void Explode(View view) {
    Explode explode = new Explode();
    explode.setEpicenterCallback(new MyEpicenterCallback(view));
    getWindow().setExitTransition(explode);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions =
            ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this);
    startActivity(intent, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
}
```

...and here is the Callback I have created:

```
public class MyEpicenterCallback extends Transition.EpicenterCallback {
    View epicenterView;

    public MyEpicenterCallback(View view) {
        epicenterView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public Rect onGetEpicenter(Transition transition) {
        return new Rect(epicenterView.getLeft(), epicenterView.getTop(), epicenterView.getRight(), epicenterView.getBottom());
    }
}
```

onGetEpicenter is never called. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

I found that strange as well. Looks like the epicenter callback gets overwritten in [ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c80f952/core/java/android/app/ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java) and there is not much you can do against it.

One somehow dirty workaround would be do prevent the change, e.g. like so:

```
explode = new Explode() {
    {
        super.setEpicenterCallback(new Transition.EpicenterCallback() {
            @Override
            public Rect onGetEpicenter(Transition transition) {
                return epicenter;
            }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void setEpicenterCallback(EpicenterCallback epicenterCallback) {
    }
};

getWindow().setExitTransition(explode);
```

epicenter is a Rect field in your activity that you can set before calling startActivity.

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I thought I'd mention that in the common case of having shared elements in your transition, the FIRST shared element will automatically become the epicentre of the transition. This seems reasonable for most purposes.